# IntelliJ IDEA: use different indentation for continuation of method call versus other continuation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation

I have a style of indenting Java that's perhaps slightly idiosyncratic, I frequently write:

```
object.myMethod(
    myFirstArgument, mySecondArgument, myThirdArgument, myFourthArgument,
    myFifthArgument, mySixthArgument
);
```

So I use a four-space continuation in this context, when it's the continuation of a method call.  However I use a two-space indentation in other continuation contexts:

```
String myComplicatedString = SOME_CONSTANT_STRING + SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT
  + YET_ANOTHER_CONSTANT + "-my-weird-suffix";

Object myBuiltObject = BuilderPattern.withArg(42)
  .withException(UltimateException.class)
  .withBlah("whatever");
```

Is there any way to get IntelliJ IDEA to use a different indentation in these contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there are only two types of indents you can set in IntelliJ code style settings - normal indent and continuation indent. So I'm afraid it's not possible to set continuation indent size based on context at the moment.

I suggest opening a new issue in JetBrains' YouTrack for this functionality.

Comment: I found out that there is an existing issue covering similar functionality.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120057

Comment: Note: the concept of continuation indent (usually configured to twice as much as the regular indent size): Continuation indent can occur if e.g. you wrap the first line of an "if" or "for" or "try" statement.